# Python Pandas-Update a data frame column with values from another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i'm trying get better at Python and decided to do some analysis on one of my passions. Wrestling! In this case, Japanese Wrestling!

Basically I'm trying to update values in one data frame from another data frame. Here's what my first data frame looks like

```
|   | Wrestler          | Matches | DMR |
| 0 | TETSUYA NAITO     | 9       | 0   |
| 1 | HIROSHI TANAHASHI | 9       | 0   |
| 2 | BAD LUCK FALE     | 9       | 0   |
| 3 | KOTA IBUSHI       | 9       | 0   |
| 4 | ZACK SABRE JR.    | 9       | 0   |
| 5 | HIROOKI GOTO      | 9       | 0   |
| 6 | TOMOHIRO ISHII    | 9       | 0   |
| 7 | TOGI MAKABE       | 9       | 0   |
| 8 | YOSHI-HASHI       | 9       | 0   |
| 9 | YUJI NAGATA       | 9       | 0   |
```

The column I'm trying to update is DMR*(Dave Meltzer Ratings)* from another data frame that is generated from some data I input:

```
| Wrestler          | DMR      |
| BAD LUCK FALE     | 3.166667 |
| HIROOKI GOTO      | 3.694444 |
| HIROSHI TANAHASHI | 4.111111 |
| KOTA IBUSHI       | 4.222222 |
| TETSUYA NAITO     | 4        |
| TOGI MAKABE       | 3.611111 |
| TOMOHIRO ISHII    | 4.25     |
| YOSHI-HASHI       | 3.638889 |
| YUJI NAGATA       | 4.138889 |
| ZACK SABRE JR.    | 3.611111 |
```

I have a feeling it's something simple but I couldn't find anything that would explain how to do it. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Shan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series`:

```
df1['DMR'] = df1['Wrestler'].map(df2.set_index('Wrestler')['DMR'])
```

Or [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with `left join` and [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) for remove column:

```
df1 = pd.merge(df1.drop('DMR', axis=1), df2, how='left')
```

---

```
print (df1)
            Wrestler  Matches       DMR
0      TETSUYA NAITO        9  4.000000
1  HIROSHI TANAHASHI        9  4.111111
2      BAD LUCK FALE        9  3.166667
3        KOTA IBUSHI        9  4.222222
4     ZACK SABRE JR.        9  3.611111
5       HIROOKI GOTO        9  3.694444
6     TOMOHIRO ISHII        9  4.250000
7        TOGI MAKABE        9  3.611111
8        YOSHI-HASHI        9  3.638889
9        YUJI NAGATA        9  4.138889
```

Notice:

Values in `Wrestler` column in `df2` have to be unique.

Comment: Thanks Jezrael, I was familiar with map but couldn't get it to work, Appreciate the quick reply and the values in df2 are unique so no issues there!

Answer (score 0):

So I am going to assume your first dataframe is called df1 and your second one is called df2. Then this would work:

```
df1 = df1.drop('DMR', 1)
df = merge(df1, df2, on = 'Wrestler')
```

Just drop DMR from the first dataframe and then merge them on the Wrestler column.